# Chrome parse date with 11 minute difference

Tags: google-chrome

I saw a similar answer here [Parsed date has minute difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270403/parsed-date-has-minute-difference) but it's not exactly the same

I have a problem with google chrome. I have an application developed with GWT. This application sent an RPC to a server, and it get some data in return.

In this data there are some Date object. Seeing this date in EDGE and Firefox everything is ok but in Chrome they have 11 minute less.

I don't think it's a "code parsing" problem... because if I watch the RPC answer in Firefox and Chrome, I can see the RPC answer already wrong.
In firefox I see the object as `"jsdate: Date 1800-01-01-01T07:30:00.000Z"` and this is what I expect

In chrome I see the object as `"jsdate: 1800 08:19:56 GMT+0049"`

you can see image of devtool screenshot with the link below

[firefox](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UCCcF2CHVPe_oeyN89uO62ZQYVrdCVV2)

[chrome](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QSbJprrJolUl7RpjOI8ScWLHNFiFNwS6)

In chrome version 69 i get this
In older version of chrome (for example 63) i get the same as firefox

Comment: I just tried with an older version of chrome and it's working correctly (version 63.0.3239.108)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the time in Italy in 1800 was a bit different than now -
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/italy/rome (pick 1800 - 1849 in "Time zone changes for:")
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/italy

> In Italy, standard time was introduced in 1893. Until then, the
>   country had been using solar mean time, based on Italy's longitude. It
>   was 49 minutes and 56 seconds ahead of GMT, then the world's time
>   standard.
>
> In 1893, Italy advanced its clocks by 10 minutes and 4 seconds, so the
>   local time was exactly 1 hour ahead of GMT. The country still uses
>   this local time as standard time today.

So I am not sure this is a bug in Chrome, but a feature. I think Chrome simply updated their time zone data to include data for older times and it is now more accurate. Other browsers may follow suite at some point.

Since `new Date(`...`)` converts the input to the local time, the time zone is taken into account.